# When do Angular 2 services initialize

Tags: angular, service

I have a shared service that I am using to store global variables like authentication tokens.  I am having issues ensuring that the value is getting updated and that the newest value is being used in my components.  For example:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalVariablesProvider {

  private auth_token: string;

  constructor() {}

  getAuthToken() {
    return this.auth_token
  }

  setAuthToken(auth_token) {
    this.auth_token = auth_token
  }
}
```

and then in my `login-component` I set the `auth_token`:

```
this.clientService.login(user).subscribe(
  successData => {
    this.current_user = successData["user"]
    this.globalService.setAuthToken(this.current_user.auth_token)
  }
}
```

but when I navigate to a different page / use a new component, occasionally the `auth_token` is out of sync (I believe if the service is being re-initialized and losing the `auth_token` value).

```
this.auth_token = this.globalVarService.getAuthToken()
// occasionally returns null
```

Is there a way to ensure that nce this variable is set, the value remains even after being injected into another component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, import service in the root module of your app and insert it into `providers` section in NgModule declaration. From now it will act like a singleton and will be available for all components in your app without passing it into each component's `providers`.

If you want to always keep `auth_token` in sync with each component you inject this service to, you might use Subjects from `rxjs` package, which is included in Angular installation. There is a good post [on Medium](https://netbasal.com/understanding-subjects-in-rxjs-55102a190f3) about it. For example:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'

@Injectable()
export class GlobalVariablesProvider {

  private auth_token: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>()

  constructor() {}

  getAuthToken() {
    return this.auth_token
  }

  setAuthToken(auth_token) {
    this.auth_token.next(auth_token)
  }
}
```

Then, inject it in components you need. Then, if you need to get current token, instead of using value received from `getAuthToken()`, you can subscribe to it. So, your component will be always in sync with current token:

```
this.globalVarService
  .getAuthToken()
  .subscribe(token => {
    this.auth_token = token
  })
```

Comment: I'm familiar with observables.  I guess "inject" was the wrong term.  I only use it as a singleton, and call it in my `constructor()`.  I'm working on implementation now

Answer (score 2):

Declare service in root module to make it `Singleton`, since angular has hierarchical injector.

Comment: So I already do in app module under `providers`.  Don't I need to inject it into my component if I want to use its functions in the component?  How else would I access `this.globalVarService.getAuthToken()`

Comment: @JeremyThomas Yes you need. Declaring service in root module (one which you `bootstrapModule` in `main.ts`) ensures that **same instance** of service is provided whenever it is requested (injected into constructor).